# Vue.js : subscribe and modify all events from parent to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to pass all events from child to parent, but modify them on the fly.
I know there is `v-on="$listeners"`, but I can't found a way to change all events.
Let's say there are a `slider` component, my `middleware` component which bind all events from child to the `parent` component:

```html
// Slider component emit events: input, change, click, dragstart, dragend, dragging

// Middleware.vue
<template>
    <slider v-on="$listeners" />
</template>

// Parent.vue
<template>
    <middleware @click="parentClickCustomMethod" @dragstart="parentDragstartCustomMethod" ... />
</template>
```

With this code, I can attach all events I want from parent to child.
[Vue.js doc here for $listeners.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners)

But now, I want to modify all events on the fly and don't repeat my-self:

```html
// Slider component emit events: input, change, click, dragstart, dragend, dragging...

// Middleware.vue with custom method
<template>
    <slider
        v-model="myValue"
        @click="$emit('click', customMethod(myValue))"
        @change="$emit('change', customMethod(myValue))"
        @dragstart="$emit('dragstart', customMethod(myValue))"
        ...
    />
</template>

// Parent.vue
<template>
    <middleware @click="parentClickCustomMethod" @dragstart="parentDragstartCustomMethod" ... />
</template>
```

How to use `customMethod` with `$listeners`?

**Edit:** What I tried?

```
v-on="customMethod($listeners)"
```

> I got all parent listeners, but how to know which event was emitted?

```
v-on="customMethod($event)"
```

> Return error: `Property or method "$event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

```
v-on="customMethod"
```

> Return error: `v-on without argument expects an Object value`

Comment: $listeners should be an object -> iterate its keys and change or wrap those methods?

Comment: What error are you getting? Any additional parameters emitted should be available as an argument in the capturing method.

Comment: There is no error. I just want to know how to not repeat event (@click="$emit('click'... @change="$emit('change'... ) and do it with one single command..

Comment: Possible related issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7862